# AWS Identity federation and AWS Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm having some confusion with regards to identity federation in AWS. Mainly on how federation can work when using AWS organizations.

So, as far as I have seen, one can use leverage things such as SSO, and use SSO as an IdP for then, via SAML2.0 (Still need to really learn how that works) provide access to AWS Console lets say.

But, how does that work if I'm using some sort of AWS organization?

Lets say I have an Organization, and that organization has an account that is in charge of managing the security of the whole organization. Services such as Security Hub will be enabled in that account.

How would I be able to, via SSO, provide access to that account for some specific users that are signin in via SSO?

Not looking for a straight answer really, but more or less some direction on what should I research for achieving this, and whether or not such things can be automated up to a certain point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're correct, you can use AWS SSO as an IdP to federate to your AWS account (AWS console as well as AWS CLIv2).
2. In order to use AWS SSO, you have to already be using AWS Organizations, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/manage-your-accounts.html : "AWS Single Sign-On is integrated with AWS Organizations so that administrators can pick multiple AWS accounts whose users need single sign-on (SSO) access to the AWS Management Console."
3. As for how you'd provide access to the Security Hub account you've designated as the delegated admin account, its the same as any other AWS SSO user. You'd create a user, then probably assign it to a group. Then create a permission set. Then goto the Security Hub account, and assign the user or group to the account while selecting the permissions set to go with the user/group when federating to that account.

Once you do the above, you'll be able to SSO right away via your user or group into that account - its rather straightforward.